# Want to identify which provider is providing me the location (whether gps or cellular/wifi network) in android

Tags: android

I am using android fused location API. Is there any way to determine the provider using fused location API or any other API?

`location.getprovider()` gives the result "fused" and does not provide the provider details.

The API does not necessarily be the fused API. Any solution would be appreciated as long as it identify the location provider (gps or mobile network or wifi).

Comment: The **point** behind the fused location provider is that the location is **not** from "gps or mobile network or wifi" individually. The location is synthesized from multiple data sources, combined using proprietary algorithms.

Comment: Is there any other way to identify the provider, using some other API or something else?

Comment: If you want location data from a single source, so you know what that source is, use `LocationManager` and request a specific provider (e.g., `GPS_PROVIDER`).

Comment: i think this could be a workaround for now. Thanks for the help and let me know if there is any other better way.